# Deleting equal values of dict in list python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got dict in list:

```
[{'Name':'John','Age':'20'},{'Name':'John','Age':'22'},{'Name':'John','Age':'23'},{'Name':'Marie','Age':'20'}]
```

And I want only `[{'Name':'John','Age':'23'},{'Name':'Marie','Age':'20'}]`
How can i achieve that?

Comment: why did you choose age 23, it's not equal to any of the other dictionaries in the list?

Comment: manualy. maybe something like raw_input()

Comment: Do they always only have "Name" and "Age" keys?  Are there more keys that need to be preserved?

Comment: @mgilson yes. this is using for example. i sure can use date of birth. but age is easier for this example

Comment: equal is complicated in a dict as it is not an immutable type (and not hashable, too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just feed the values into another dict using the name as the key, if you add the same name twice it clobbers the old entry, this has the effect of uniquifying your list by name.

```
data_structure = [{'Name':'John','Age':'20'},{'Name':'John','Age':'22'},{'Name':'John','Age':'23'},{'Name':'Marie','Age':'20'}]
d={}
for x in data_structure:
    d[x['Name']] = x

d.values()
>>> [{'Age': '23', 'Name': 'John'}, {'Age': '20', 'Name': 'Marie'}]
```

UPDATE: deleting entries based on user input

```
data_structure = [{'Name':'John','Age':'20'},{'Name':'John','Age':'22'},{'Name':'John','Age':'23'},{'Name':'Marie','Age':'20'}]

while 1:
    name = raw_input("Enter Name: ")
    if not len(name): break
    age = int(raw_input("Enter Age: "))
    flag=1
    while flag:
        for idx, d in enumerate(data_structure):
            if 'Name' in d and \
                'Age' in d and \
                int(d['Age']) != age and \
                d['Name'] == name:
                data_structure.pop(idx)
                flag=2
                break
        flag-=1
```

Comment: wow. that's an idea! thanks. but how it will 'choose' the name?

Comment: do you mean how do we know which entries from the list get saved and which get thrown away? that is more or less random as the values in a dictionary are not guaranteed to be in any particular order when you iterate over them. we could add a condition if, say, you want to preserve the entry with the highest age

Comment: can i manualy write age? maybe with raw_input()?

Comment: oh so you want to input something like "John 23" and then remove all Johns from the list except the one that is 23?

Comment: you're right. something like this.

Comment: updated to reflect this

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that a data structure which maps Name to Age is more appropriate here (`{'John':23}`).  In this case, I'll create a dictionary which maps a name to a list of ages and then I'll re-create the list using only the maximum age...

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for dd in lst:
    name,age = dd['Name'],dd['Age']
    d[name].append(age)
new_list = [{'Name':n,'Age':max(ages)} for n,ages in d.items()]
```

Comment: that's an idea, but not for me. thx :)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to group the items considered equals. In your case, 2 dicts with the same `Name` value are equal:

edit - to use groupby, the items must be next to one another. a quick way is to sort, using the same name getting lambda:

```
nameL = lambda x: x['Name']
equals = groupby(sorted(a, key=nameL), key=nameL)
```

Then, you'll have to choose (here, at random, replace `choice` by any method of choosing)

```
from random import choice
res = []
for name, items in equals:
    res.append(choice(list(items)))
```

Comment: This may not work for : `[{'Age': '23', 'Name': 'John'}, {'Age': '20', 'Name': 'Marie'}, {'Age': '22', 'Name': 'John'}]`

Comment: true. one would need to sort the list first to use this method.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
d = [{'Name':'John','Age':'20'},{'Name':'John','Age':'22'},{'Name':'John','Age':'23'},{'Name':'Marie','Age':'20'}]
import itertools
d = sorted(d, key=lambda x: (x['Name'], x['Age']))
grouped_by_name = itertools.groupby(d, lambda x: x['Name'])
[list(entries)[-1] for name, entries in grouped_by_name]
# [{'Age': '23', 'Name': 'John'}, {'Age': '20', 'Name': 'Marie'}]
```